Merge xml input from an external variable into another xml input using xslt
I need to merge an xml input that I stored in a variable with another xml input message using xslt.
XML Input:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<aggregatedd>
  <cal:stack xmlns:cal="urn:calabrio">
    <cal:timeoff>
      <cal:person>473937f5-9222-4187-9d30-afe000c44702</cal:person>
      <cal:date>2024-11-01</cal:date>
      <cal:timeofftype>USA_ABS002</cal:timeofftype>
      <cal:hours>4.50</cal:hours>
    </cal:timeoff>
  </cal:stack>
  <wd:TimeOff-Stack xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR_INT_Calabrio_Workday_TimeOff_by_Time_Period">
    <wd:TimeOff-Entry>
      <wd:WID>10636</wd:WID>
      <wd:wd-key>20241107USAABS002800</wd:wd-key>
      <wd:Date>2024-11-07</wd:Date>
      <wd:Timeoff>USA_ABS002</wd:Timeoff>
      <wd:Hours>8.00</wd:Hours>
      <wd:EntryID>TIME_OFF_ENTRY-6-1136743</wd:EntryID>
    </wd:TimeOff-Entry>
  </wd:TimeOff-Stack>
  <wd:TimeOff-Stack xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR_Calabrio_TO_Eligible_Worker_Report">
    <wd:TimeOff-Entry>
      <wd:WID>10636</wd:WID>
      <wd:wd-key>20241107USAABS002800</wd:wd-key>
      <wd:Date>2024-11-07</wd:Date>
      <wd:Timeoff>USA_ABS002</wd:Timeoff>
      <wd:Hours>8.00</wd:Hours>
      <wd:EntryID>TIME_OFF_ENTRY-6-1136743</wd:EntryID>
    </wd:TimeOff-Entry>
  </wd:TimeOff-Stack>
</aggregatedd>

the external variable contains another xml message
something like
XML Input 2(in a extrenal variable):
  <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR_Calabrio_TO_Eligible_Worker_Report">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
      <wd:WID>10636</wd:WID>
      <wd:Wiser_ID>10636</wd:Wiser_ID>
      <wd:Person_Id>473937f5-9222-4187-9d30-afe000c44702</wd:Person_Id>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
      <wd:WID>10636</wd:WID>
      <wd:Wiser_ID>2222</wd:Wiser_ID>
      <wd:Person_Id>11111-22222-4187-9d30-afe000c44702</wd:Person_Id>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
  </wd:Report_Data>

I have looked at similar posts(they needed to merge them under matching groups) and tried this xslt as I simply want to add this into my main aggregator node and use later for further processing. The xslt is failing. I cannot really process this in oxygen as the variable is external(part of my overall studio assembly).
XSLT:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR_INT_Calabrio_Workday_TimeOff_by_Time_Period
    CR_Calabrio_TO_Eligible_Worker_Report"
    
    xmlns:cal="urn:calabrio"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent = "yes"  />
    <xsl:param name="wdwiserreport"/>
    <xsl:variable name="report-doc" select="doc($wdwiserreport)"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="aggregatedd">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::cal:stack)] |@* | node()[not(self::wd:TimeOff-Stack)]" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of($report-doc)" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
</xsl:stylesheet>

I have referred to similar questions posted here and tried the xslt I shared above but receiving errors. Please advise how I can use an external variable and merge that into my main xml. Thank you. Appreciate any inputs.
I simply would like to add the variable output to my aggregator node to be further processed
Desired Output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<aggregatedd>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR_Calabrio_TO_Eligible_Worker_Report">
        <wd:Report_Entry>
          <wd:WID>10636</wd:WID>
          <wd:Wiser_ID>10636</wd:Wiser_ID>
          <wd:Person_Id>473937f5-9222-4187-9d30-afe000c44702</wd:Person_Id>
        </wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Report_Entry>
          <wd:WID>10636</wd:WID>
          <wd:Wiser_ID>2222</wd:Wiser_ID>
          <wd:Person_Id>11111-22222-4187-9d30-afe000c44702</wd:Person_Id>
        </wd:Report_Entry>
      </wd:Report_Data>
<cal:stack xmlns:cal="urn:calabrio">
   <cal:timeoff>
      <cal:person>473937f5-9222-4187-9d30-afe000c44702</cal:person>
      <cal:date>2024-11-01</cal:date>
      <cal:timeofftype>USA_ABS002</cal:timeofftype>
      <cal:hours>4.50</cal:hours>
   </cal:timeoff>
</cal:stack>
   <wd:TimeOff-Stack xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR_INT_Calabrio_Workday_TimeOff_by_Time_Period">
      <wd:TimeOff-Entry>
         <wd:WiserID>10636</wd:WiserID>
         <wd:wd-key>20241107USAABS002800</wd:wd-key>
         <wd:Date>2024-11-07</wd:Date>
         <wd:Timeoff>USA_ABS002</wd:Timeoff>
         <wd:Hours>8.00</wd:Hours>
         <wd:EntryID>TIME_OFF_ENTRY-6-1136743</wd:EntryID>
      </wd:TimeOff-Entry>
   </wd:TimeOff-Stack>
   <wd:TimeOff-Stack xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR_Calabrio_TO_Eligible_Worker_Report">
<wd:TimeOff-Entry>
<wd:WiserID>10636</wd:WiserID>
<wd:wd-key>20241107USAABS002800</wd:wd-key>
<wd:Date>2024-11-07</wd:Date>
<wd:Timeoff>USA_ABS002</wd:Timeoff>
<wd:Hours>8.00</wd:Hours>
<wd:EntryID>TIME_OFF_ENTRY-6-1136743</wd:EntryID>
</wd:TimeOff-Entry>
</wd:TimeOff-Stack></aggregatedd>


Currently both XML input samples appear as one long line, it is very hard for us to understand the structure of your data that way. And of course if you get an error and want us to help explain and resolve it provide the exact error message and ways to reproduce it; if you want to merge data you and don't know how to achieve that with XSLT then at least post a sample of the desired output you want for the two input samples, together with some textual explanation in what way data needs to be merged. You can often use xsl:key and the key function to cross reference two documents.

It seems
<xsl:template match="aggregatedd">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$report-doc, node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

would suffice to create the now posted desired result.
